# Kotlin chunked and map

Tags: android, kotlin

I am quite new to all things Android and Kotlin. I am currently working with an Android app from Punch Through:
(Blog: https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/)
(GitHub: https://github.com/PunchThrough/ble-starter-android)

The app connects with a BLE peripheral and allows the user to enter text to send to the peripheral via UART.

I am struggling interpreting what the following code means / does:

```
with(hexField.text.toString()) {
  if (isNotBlank() && isNotEmpty()) {
    val bytes = hexToBytes()
    ConnectionManager.writeCharacteristic(device, characteristic, bytes)
  }
}
```

Where hexField.text.toString() is the text entered in the EditText field by the user,
and
where hexToBytes() is defined as:

```
private fun String.hexToBytes() =
 this.chunked(2).map { it.toUpperCase(Locale.US).toInt(16).toByte() }.toByteArray()
```

I have tried this a few times, always entering “111” and have am using Timber() to output the result of bytes. This result varies every time, for example:

```
[B@2acf801
[B@476814a
[B@e9a70e5
[B@10172a0
```

So, I assume that only the first three characters are relevant, and somehow there is no end of line / string information.
So perhaps I am only interested in: [B@.......

```
B@ = 0x 5B 42 40
Hex: 5B4240
Dec: 5980736
Bin: 10110110100001001000000
```

So then I try (and fail) to interpret / breakdown what this code might be doing.
The first thing I struggle with is understanding the order of operation.
Here's my guess....

Given EditText entry, in this case I entered "111"

First:

```
this.chunked(2)
```

would produce something like:

```
"11 and "01"
```

Second, for each of the two items ("11 and "01"):

```
it.toUpperCase(Locale.US).toInt(16).toByte()
```

would produce byte values:

```
17 and 1
```

Third:

```
.map    .toByteArray()
```

Would produce something like:

```
[1,7,1]
```

or

```
[0x01, 0x07, 0x1]
```

or

```
[0x0x31, 0x37, 0x31]
```

So, as you can see, I am getting lost in this!
Can anyone help me deconstruct this code?

Thanks in advance

Garrett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried this a few times, always entering “111” and have am using Timber() to output the result of bytes. This result varies every time

The output when you try to print a `ByteArray` (or any array on the JVM) doesn't show the *contents* of the array, but its type and address in memory. This is why you don't get the same result every time.

In order to print an array's contents, use `theArray.contentToString()` (instead of plain interpolation or `.toString()`).

Regarding the interpretation of the code, you almost got it right, but there are a few mistakes here and there.

`this.chunked(2)` on the string `"111"` would return a list of 2 strings: `["11", "1"]` - there is no padding here, just the plain strings with max size of 2.

Then, `map` takes each of those elements individually and applies the transformation `it.toUpperCase(Locale.US).toInt(16).toByte()`. This one makes the string uppercase (doesn't change anything for the `1`s), and then converts the string into an integer by interpreting it in base 16, and then truncates this integer to a single byte. This part you got right, it transforms `"11"` into 17 and `"1"` into `1`, but the `map {...}` operation transforms the list `["11", "1"]` into `[17, 1]`, it doesn't take the digits of 17 individually.

Now `toByteArray()` just converts the `List` (`[17, 1]`) into a byte array of the same values, so it's still `[17, 1]`.

Comment: Thank you Joffrey - very clear answer and, of course, correct - I added the .contentToString() and got the expected result: [17,1]